# Separator not coming in RecyclerView in a Dialog Box

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a custom dialog box which contains a recyclerView. I polulate my recyclerview using a layout file. When I populate data in this view, the separators are not present and items are closer together. When I use same layout file to polulate a recyclerView in a Fragment, it works as expected. The recyclerView layout file and item layout file are same in both cases. I am attaching scren shots to clarify things

### In recyclerView in fragment. **There are separators in this.**

[image]

### In recyclerView in Dialogbox. **There are no separators in this**

[image]

These are my layout files

### RecylerView layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:id="@+id/explore_recyclerView"
    android:paddingTop="1dp"
    ></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

### This is my item layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:elevation="3dp"
android:paddingBottom="1dp"
>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/post_card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Arial New"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/preview_font_name"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Monotype Solutions"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/preview_imageview"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="center">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_star_outline_24dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:tint="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Favourite"
                android:textSize="12dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/font_view_preview_layout">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_visibility_24dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:tint="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Preview"
            android:textSize="12dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/preview_buy_layout">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_24dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:tint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Buy Now"
                android:textSize="12dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/preview_similarity_layout">
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_24dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:tint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Similar Fonts"
                android:textSize="12dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

### This is my code to inflate Fragment containing the RecyclerView

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_explore_view, container, false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.explore_recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
}
```

### This is how I inflate my dialog box

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_explore_view);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.explore_recyclerView);

    getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For dividers in `RecyclerView`, you have to use ItemDecoration.

Create `DividerItemDecoration.java` as below:

```
public class DividerItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private Drawable mDivider;

    public DividerItemDecoration(Context context) {
        mDivider = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.line_divider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
        int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

        int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View child = parent.getChildAt(i);

            RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

            int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
            int bottom = top + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();

            mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
            mDivider.draw(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Have a shape `line_divider.xml` in drawable as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <size
        android:width="1dp"
        android:height="1dp" />

    <solid android:color="@color/colorTextHint" />

</shape>
```

Lastly, have this color in `colors.xml`:

```
<color name="colorTextHint">#9f9f9f</color>
```

Finally, use the `DividerItemDecoration.java` as:

```
mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(**context**));
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to use this code in 'item layout file'

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.1dp"
    android:background="#D3D3D3"
   />
```

Answer (score -3):

Add this two line in `android.support.v7.widget.CardView`

```
app:cardElevation="2dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

Comment: this is not what the question was asked for